# 'CustomDF' object has no attribute '_mgr'

Tags: python, csv

I tried to read csv file using class. It showed an error message : **'CustomDF' object has no attribute '_mgr',**
when I pass df = CustomDF('test.csv'), support needed!

```
class CustomDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def  __init__(self, filename):
        self = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are subclassing `pd.DataFrame` rather than just doing `df = pd.read_csv(filename)`? If you want to do your dataframe stuff inside a class, using an attribute of the class rather than inheritence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the parent class `pd.DataFrame` in your `__init__` function with the dataset you just imported, see the code below.

```py
class CustomDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def  __init__(self, filename):
        super().__init__(pd.read_csv(filename))
```